# JNotify : Supervise a directory all the time

Tags: java, multithreading

In my project, I use some files in a directory. And for some reasons, I must load the files at the launch of the project, and if there is an action on these files, I must reload them (in a HashMap)
For the moment, I load them just at the moment of the use, but I want to do this at the load of application, and let the [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) working all the time.

I am working on a web project. Can I have some help please ?
thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a Servlet that I launch in the begining of the application.
I create the JNotify in the init() method, and because it have Listeners, it will listen to the directories that I want to watch all the life of the Servlet.
Thnx for you answers.

Answer (score 1):

Other than manually polling the file system yourself, JNotify (or a library like it) is probably your best option for now.  There are [changes planned for Java 7](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/) that will address the need for this (see the WatchService section on the linked page).

#### Edit:

On closer reading of your question, I understand that you're not really looking for alternatives, but for help in using JNotify.  See the [code samples](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/sample.html) section.  You need to add a watch to the directory or files you're watching, and add your own class as a Listener for change events.  You'll need to implement `JNotifyListener` in your code and handle the events that you're interested in.

Comment: I use the JNotifyListener, and everything is working. What I want to do, is that the listener works all the time, like as in a servlet that I launch in the start of the application.
Do you see ??
Thnx a lot

Comment: @taichimaro: You should be able to do that from a servlet by setting its `<load-on-startup>` parameter in your web.xml file.  This will cause your servlet's init() method to be run when the server starts up, from which you can launch a daemon thread to handle notifications from JNotify.

Comment: @taichimaro: Take a look at [TIJ Daemon threads](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ315_005.htm).  Your thread class will need to implement `JNotifyListener` and handle the events that are generated when a file changes.  Your servlet's init() method will need to instantiate and run your custom thread.